# Git: Writing objects: 100% but doesn't show in github

Tags: git

I'm using VS code.

I have nothing in the Source Control section

If I run git status I get

```
On branch text-branch
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/text-branch' by 4 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
user@TG-UYHD users-app %
```

If I do git push I get

```
Enumerating objects: 28, done.
Counting objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 151.25 MiB | 27.13 MiB/s, done.
Total 17 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

It looks like it goes to 100% but it doesn't show in github, am I doing something wrong.

How can I fix this.

Is there a way I can remove these commits stopping it

Comment: Are you sure GitHub is the remote you're pushing to? What does `git remote -v` show you?

Comment: `git remote -v` shows the correct remote on github. I've changed the repo name here but like `origin  https://github.the-repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.the-repo.git (push)`

Comment: And are you looking at the right branch on GitHub's web UI? What do you mean *"doesn't show in github"*?

Comment: Yes I'm looking the correct branch in github. If I click on commit on the branch in github it doesn't show the latest commit.The last commit is form yesterday

Comment: There's not much more we can do then. If the git status is up to date with the remote and the remote and branch are correct, it's unclear why you're seeing something different through the web UI.

Comment: Your `git push` output *should* end with lines telling you about the successful update of some name(s) over on the Git repo at GitHub, after the `Total 17` line. What did those lines look like?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue right now, writing object says 100% and done; but no files are found at the repo, also there are no names displayed of the files that were updated. Did you solve the problem?